# how to pass the API parameter and parameter is in array

Tags: swift, api, post, alamofire

**How to pass array parameter**

> Parameter
>   [
>     {
>       "id": 0,
>       "followerId": 1030,
>       "followingId": 1033,
>       "followerName": "string",
>       "followingName": "string",
>       "createdDate": "string",
>       "message": "string"
>     }
>   ] `//how to solve this array`

**API Function**

```
class func postFollowers(params:[String: Any],success:@escaping([FollowingDataProvider]) -> Void, failure:@escaping (String) -> Void){
    var request =  RequestObject()
    request = Services.servicePostForFollower(param: params)

    APIManager.Singleton.sharedInstance.callWebServiceWithRequest(rqst: request, withResponse: { (response) in
        if (response?.isValid)!
        {
            //success()
            print(response?.object as! JSON)
            success(self.followingJSONarser(responseObject: response?.object as! JSON));

            //followingJSONarser(responseObject: response?.object as! JSON)
        }
        else
        {
            failure((response?.error?.description)!)
        }
    }, withError: {
        (error) in
        failure((error?.description)!)
    })
}
```

**Parsing**

```
static func followingJSONarser(responseObject:JSON) -> [FollowingDataProvider]{
    var dataProvider = [FollowingDataProvider]()
    let jsonDataa = responseObject["data"]
    print(jsonDataa)
    let newJSON = jsonDataa["data"].arrayValue
    print(newJSON)


    for item in newJSON{
        print(item)
        dataProvider.append(FollowingDataProvider(id: item["userId"].intValue, followerId: item["userId"].intValue, followingId: item["followingId"].intValue, followerName: item["userName"].stringValue, followingName: item["followingName"].stringValue, createdDate: item["createdDate"].stringValue, message: item["message"].stringValue))
    }
    return dataProvider
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to combine **SwiftyJson** with `Codable`

```
struct Root: Codable {
  let id, followerID, followingID: Int
  let followerName, followingName, createdDate, message: String

 enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case followerID = "followerId"
    case followingID = "followingId"
    case followerName, followingName, createdDate, message
 }
}
```

---

```
if let con = response?.object as? JSON {
   do {
       let itemData = try con.rawData() 
       let res  = try JSONDecoder().decode([Root].self, from: itemData) 
       print(res)
   catch {
      print(error)
   }
}
```

Also avoid force-unwraps with json

```
response?.object as! JSON
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your code you're trying to parse data from API, you can use `SwiftyJSON` with `Alamofire` to create an HTTP request (post,get,put,delete,etc)

You should use `arrayObject` instead of `arrayValue`

Your code missing the right definition to data parsing

```
static func followingJSONarser(responseObject:JSON) -> [FollowingDataProvider]{
    var dataProvider = [FollowingDataProvider]()
    var itemClass = [ItemClass]()
    let jsonDataa = responseObject["data"] as! Dictionary
    let newJSON = jsonDataa["data"].arrayObject as! Array
```

Now create a dataModel class to cast data to it

```
class ItemsClass:NSObject{
    var id:Int = 0
    var followerId:Int = 0
    var followingId:Int = 0
    var followerName:String = ""
    var followingName:String = ""
    var createdDate:String = ""
    var message:String = ""

    init(data:JSON) {
        self.id = data["userId"].intValue
        self.followerId = data["userId"].intValue
        self.followingId = data["followingId"].intValue
        self.followerName  = data["userName"].stringValue
        self.followingName = data["followingName"].stringValue
        self.createdDate = data["createdDate"].stringValue
        self.message = data["message"].stringValue
    }

}
    for item in newJSON{
        dataProvider.append(itemClass)
    }
    return dataProvider
}`
```